# Pagination error for google clone script

Tags: php

I am currently using greekdevs google clone script, the script normally nothing wrong, but when we click on the pagination, the number of pages displayed increasing multiples. I've tried replacing to $page = $_GET['page'] * 1 + 1;

however instead search results in reduced 1 rather than 10.

here the script http://sourceforge.net/projects/googleclone/

this my site using that script http://google.ocim.pw/search.php?q=stackoverflow

Thank you in advance.